# Deployed contract does not show up on the remix.solidity

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

I am using a private ethereum network and I am using remix.solidity (http://remix.ethereum.org) to deploy my contract.

First I connect into my private-network:

`Run` => `Environment` and selected `Web3 Provide`
There will be a window opening asking “Are you sure want to connect to an ethereum node?” Clicked OK. Please note that, the connection is established to my private network and there is no problem on that side.

[image]

Than I deployed my contract via on `Run` tab and clicking `Create` button that is next to my contract.

[image]

After some time, I can see that my contract (simple hello-world contract) is deployed on my network status (as the transaction it show up), but I do not see the deployed contract on the remix solidity browser (on console it hangs as `creation of greeter pending...`), so I cannot obtain its address and access into my contract.

**[Q]** What should I do to see the address of deployed contract on the remix solidity? Does anyone face with the similar bug?

I also asked as a Github issue: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you entering the RPC endpoint when you choose to use a custom web3 provider? Another common problem is using the `https` version of Remix. Edit the URL in your browser and make it `http` instead of `https` when using a custom RPC endpoint

Comment: RPC end point is entered as follows: `geth --datadir $DATADIR/private --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --networkid 12345 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --rpcaddr "localhost"`. Let me try with `http`, that is probably be the issue. @JAG

Comment: Make sure you use the `http` version, when putting the custom RPC endpoint into Remix it should only be the ip address and the port that it's running from.

Comment: But contract is deployed on the network (I can see that on the network status site), there is no connection error I guess. hence remix.solidity does not show the deployed contract on its gui @JAG

Comment: I tried with `http` but stil it gives the same error. @JAG

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well. I had to disable my popup blocker(uBlock).